# error running gem5 full system on ARM bigLITTLE

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gem5

I installed gem5 on my ubuntu 18.04.5. If I run a generic fs.py ARM architecture then the simulation boots up fine no matter what configuration I use. For example:

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --kernel=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/fs_imgs/binaries/vmlinux.arm64
--disk-image=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/fs_imgs/disks/aarch32-ubuntu-natty-headless.img
```

I followed multiple tutorials to run gem5 in full system mode in ARM bigLITTLE architecture but none succeeded. I tried different disk image files, kernels and bootscript combinations and no luck. Some gives kernel panic errors and some gives:

```
[    0.199882] init: hwclock main process (592) terminated with status 1
```

For example if I use the command(which is provided in http://www.gem5.org/assets/files/ASPLOS2017_gem5_tutorial.pdf):

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/fs_bigLITTLE.py --kernel=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/linux-arm-gem5/vmlinux 
--cpu-type=atomic --dtb=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/system/arm/dt/armv8_gem5_v1_big_little_2_4.dtb --disk=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/fs_imgs/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img
```

then the output is

```
==== m5 terminal: Terminal 0 ====
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0+ (ting-bazinga@tingbazinga-Alienware-17-R5) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 5 00:17:28 CST 2021
[    0.000000] Boot CPU: AArch64 Processor [410fd070]
[    0.000000] earlycon: Early serial console at MMIO 0x1c090000 (options '')
[    0.000000] bootconsole [uart0] enabled
[    0.000000] Memory limited to 2048MB
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x00000000ff000000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 524288
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 8192 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 524288 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 15 pages/cpu @ffffffc07efc9000 s23704 r8192 d29544 u61440
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s23704 r8192 d29544 u61440 alloc=15*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 
[    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: enabling workaround for ARM erratum 832075
[    0.000000] CPU features: enabling workaround for ARM erratum 834220
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 516096
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: earlyprintk earlycon=pl011,0x1c090000 console=ttyAMA0 lpj=19988480 norandmaps loglevel=8 mem=2GB root=/dev/vda1 rw init=/sbin/init vmalloc=768MB
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    0.000000] software IO TLB [mem 0xf8a00000-0xfca00000] (64MB) mapped at [ffffffc078a00000-ffffffc07c9fffff]
[    0.000000] Memory: 1970336K/2097152K available (5478K kernel code, 138K rwdata, 1760K rodata, 236K init, 239K bss, 110432K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xffffff8000000000 - 0xffffffbdbfff0000   (   246 GB)
[    0.000000]     vmemmap : 0xffffffbdc0000000 - 0xffffffbfc0000000   (     8 GB maximum)
[    0.000000]               0xffffffbdc2000000 - 0xffffffbdc4000000   (    32 MB actual)
[    0.000000]     fixed   : 0xffffffbffa7fd000 - 0xffffffbffac00000   (  4108 KB)
[    0.000000]     PCI I/O : 0xffffffbffae00000 - 0xffffffbffbe00000   (    16 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xffffffbffc000000 - 0xffffffc000000000   (    64 MB)
[    0.000000]     memory  : 0xffffffc000000000 - 0xffffffc080000000   (  2048 MB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xffffffc000793000 - 0xffffffc0007ce000   (   236 KB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xffffffc000080000 - 0xffffffc000792a04   (  7243 KB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xffffffc0007e1000 - 0xffffffc000803b60   (   139 KB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 64.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:64 nr_irqs:64 0
[    0.000000] clk_gem5_energy_ctrl: No cpu-map in DT! Falling back to old detection method!
[    0.000000] clk_gem5_energy_ctrl: No clusters in DT! Falling back to using CPU topology!
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 and mmio timer(s) running at 25.16MHz (virt/virt).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x5cdd39714, max_idle_ns: 440795202620 ns
[    0.000001] sched_clock: 56 bits at 25MHz, resolution 39ns, wraps every 4398046511084ns
[    0.000053] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000057] Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 9994.24 BogoMIPS (lpj=19988480)
[    0.000062] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000088] Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000092] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000283] ASID allocator initialised with 256 entries
[    0.032000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.032015] CPU1: Booted secondary processor [410fd070]
[    0.032030] Brought up 2 CPUs
[    0.032037] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated.
[    0.032040] CPU features: detected feature: Privileged Access Never
[    0.032046] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL1
[    0.032053] alternatives: patching kernel code
[    0.032426] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.033559] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.033792] atomic64_test: passed
[    0.034739] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.072492] vdso: 2 pages (1 code @ ffffffc0007e9000, 1 data @ ffffffc0007e8000)
[    0.072503] hw-breakpoint: found 16 breakpoint and 16 watchpoint registers.
[    0.072876] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic allocations
[    0.072881] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.073000] /rtc@1c170000: could not find phandle
[    0.073004] ERROR: could not get clock /rtc@1c170000:apb_pclk(0)
[    0.073009] of_amba_device_create(): amba_device_add() failed (-2) for /rtc@1c170000
[    0.073053] of_amba_device_create(): amba_device_add() failed (-2) for /watchdog@2a490000
[    0.073097] of_amba_device_create(): amba_device_add() failed (-2) for /watchdog@2b060000
[    0.073141] /watchdog@1c0f0000: could not find phandle
[    0.073144] ERROR: could not get clock /watchdog@1c0f0000:apb_pclk(1)
[    0.073149] of_amba_device_create(): amba_device_add() failed (-2) for /watchdog@1c0f0000
[    0.073680] 1c090000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x1c090000 (irq = 12, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.073685] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.073685] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.073689] bootconsole [uart0] disabled
[    0.073689] bootconsole [uart0] disabled
[    0.074091] 1c0a0000.uart: ttyAMA1 at MMIO 0x1c0a0000 (irq = 13, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.074282] 1c0b0000.uart: ttyAMA2 at MMIO 0x1c0b0000 (irq = 14, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.074481] 1c0c0000.uart: ttyAMA3 at MMIO 0x1c0c0000 (irq = 15, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.074626] of_amba_device_create(): amba_device_add() failed (-2) for /kmi@1c070000
[    0.074669] of_amba_device_create(): amba_device_add() failed (-2) for /kmi@1c060000
[    0.096153] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.096283] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.100053] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.100155] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.100181] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.100200] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.100247] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.100251] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.100264] PTP clock support registered
[    0.100616] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.104724] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.104888] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.104976] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.105071] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    0.105089] UDP hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.105111] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.105175] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.105271] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.105274] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.105278] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.105281] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.105287] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 128
[    0.105477] kvm [1]: HYP mode not available
[    0.105757] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.105956] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.115434] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    0.115945] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.116020] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.116127] PCI host bridge /pci ranges:
[    0.116131]   No bus range found for /pci, using [bus 00-ff]
[    0.116138]    IO 0x2f000000..0x2f00ffff -> 0x00000000
[    0.116144]   MEM 0x40000000..0x7fffffff -> 0x00000000
[    0.117325] pci-host-generic 30000000.pci: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.117331] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    0.117336] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
[    0.117342] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x40000000-0x7fffffff] (bus address [0x00000000-0x3fffffff])
[    0.117348] pci_bus 0000:00: scanning bus
[    0.117356] pci 0000:00:01.0: [1af4:1000] type 00 class 0xff0000
[    0.117363] pci 0000:00:01.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x0000-0x001f]
[    0.117374] pci 0000:00:01.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x40000000-0x400007ff pref]
[    0.117463] pci_bus 0000:00: fixups for bus
[    0.117467] pci_bus 0000:00: bus scan returning with max=00
[    0.117478] pci 0000:00:01.0: fixup irq: got 19
[    0.117482] pci 0000:00:01.0: assigning IRQ 19
[    0.117489] pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0x40000000-0x400007ff pref]
[    0.117495] pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 0: assigned [io  0x1000-0x101f]
[    0.117603] virtio-pci 0000:00:01.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0001)
[    0.117609] virtio-pci 0000:00:01.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
[    0.117615] virtio-pci 0000:00:01.0: enabling bus mastering
[    0.119296] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.124177]  vda: vda1
[    0.128799] e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
[    0.128803] e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
[    0.128834] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.128838] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.128869] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.3.0-k
[    0.128873] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
[    0.128905] ixgbe: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 4.2.1-k
[    0.128909] ixgbe: Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.128944] ixgbevf: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Virtual Function Network Driver - version 2.12.1-k
[    0.128948] ixgbevf: Copyright (c) 2009 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
[    0.128980] i40e: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection XL710 Network Driver - version 1.3.46-k
[    0.128984] i40e: Copyright (c) 2013 - 2014 Intel Corporation.
[    0.129017] ixgb: Intel(R) PRO/10GbE Network Driver - version 1.0.135-k2-NAPI
[    0.129021] ixgb: Copyright (c) 1999-2008 Intel Corporation.
[    0.129053] i40evf: Intel(R) XL710/X710 Virtual Function Network Driver - version 1.3.33
[    0.129057] Copyright (c) 2013 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.129267] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.129408] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.133710] gem5 DVFS handler is disabled
[    0.133713] gem5-energy-ctrl loaded at ffffff800007c000
[    0.133717] gem5_energy_ctrl_mc: gem5_mc_init: DVFS handler in energy controller is disabled,                         ARM gem5 multi-cluster cpufreq driver                         will not be registered
[    0.134007] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.134011] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.134079] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.138928] EXT4-fs (vda1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    0.143482] EXT4-fs (vda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[    0.143490] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 254:1.
[    0.143795] devtmpfs: mounted
[    0.143836] Freeing unused kernel memory: 236K (ffffffc000793000 - ffffffc0007ce000)
[    0.143846] Freeing alternatives memory: 52K (ffffffc0007ce000 - ffffffc0007db000)
Mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux:  No such file or directory
[    0.184933] random: init urandom read with 6 bits of entropy available
[    0.199882] init: hwclock main process (592) terminated with status 1
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I can't find any configuration that successfully boots up a bigLITTLE arm simulation. Has anyone been able to do this?

Just FYI I found the fs_bigLITTLE.py I downloaded is different from the ones provided by others. Some tutorials use command without the --kernel option but mine says:

```
fs_bigLITTLE.py: error: argument --kernel is required
```

Comment: The boot log seem like they might be correct. Have you tried to connect to gem5 with `m5term`? Another working setup described at: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-fs-biglittle

Comment: Yeah I did use m5term, the fs.py boots up fine but can't get it to work with fs_bigLITTLE.py. Don't know if it's because the configuration setup isn't right or the packages I downloaded or anything else. I don't really understand how to use the ./run setup, but thanks so much for replying!

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in your commandline:

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/fs_bigLITTLE.py \
    --kernel=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/linux-arm-gem5/vmlinux 
    --cpu-type=atomic \
    --dtb=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/system/arm/dt/armv8_gem5_v1_big_little_2_4.dtb \
    --disk=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/fs_imgs/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img
```

The fs_bigLITTLE is by default using 1 little core and 1 big core, whereas the DTB you are using is assuming 2 big cores and 4 little cores. Removing the --dtb option should just work (relying on DTB autogeneration).
The other option is to align the command line to the dtb (using --big-cpus and --little-cpus option)

Comment: I tried both and terminal still shows the following message shortly after starting the simulation: `[    0.212156] init: hwclock main process (592) terminated with status 1` However I did found out that if I add a bootscript option in the commandline the simulation does run the scripts after showing the above error message for like almost an hour and gets stuck after completing the scripts. Is there anything you can help with the bootscript option? Anyways really appreciate your answer.

Comment: It seems like the problem is in what you run with the bootscript I would say. Could you try to avoid using a bootscript and instead run your workload manually after boot?

Comment: yeah but the problem is it doesn't boot up. Either runs into error in the middle of the simulation or completes the simulation then exits imediately (in this case if I feed it a bootscript it runs it then exits, so bootscript is the only option I've got right now). I followed many toturials online, haven't been able to boot up a simulation using _fs bigLITTLE.py_. It's really strange.

Comment: Could you try using the latest disk image provided at:

https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/fullsystem/guest_binaries ?

(ubuntu-18.04-arm64-docker.img.bz2)